# Javascript if statement returning wrong value

Tags: javascript

```
var checkHour = new Date();
checkHour.getHours();
```

If statement inside time() function seems to be returning Good Evening. At this present time it should be returning good morning. What am I doing wrong?

```
function time(){
    if((checkHour >= 0) && (checkHour <= 12)){
alert(" Good Morning");
    }else if((checkHour >= 12) && (checkHour <= 18)){
alert("Afternoon");
    }else{
      alert("Good Evening")
    }
}

time();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `checkHour` variable is loaded with the date.  You never set it's value to the hours.

Perhaps you meant the second line to read: `checkHour = checkHour.getHours();`, so your corrected code would be:

```
var checkHour = new Date();
checkHour = checkHour.getHours();

function time(){
    if((checkHour >= 0) && (checkHour <= 12)){
    alert(" Good Morning");
    }else if((checkHour >= 12) && (checkHour <= 18)){
        alert("Afternoon");
    }else{
      alert("Good Evening")
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `var checkHour = new Date().getHours();`.

Comment: Beat me to it, this is exactly what the problem is. An easy way to debug this is to `alert(checkHour)`. With the OP's code, it shows `Thu Jun 13 2013 00:48:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

CheckHour is not assigned properly, it should be

```
var checkDate = new Date();
var checkHour = checkDate.getHours();
```